# Assign variable name to desired parts in a function in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and here. Sorry If I am complicated. I created a function by `trial` name. There are some functions from my own function below.

```
write.table(pars, "C:\\Parameters\\pars_(variable name).txt")
cov12lag1_(variable name) <<- acvf(half, 1)
```

Let's say I have two different data. Data names are `jan2005` and `jan2006`
When I write function `trial(jan2005)` I want to get `pars_jan2005.txt` and also in my environment I want to see `cov12lag1_jan2005` automatically.

Also, again when I want to write `trial(jan2006)`, again I want to see `pars_jan2006.txt` and `cov12lag1_jan2006` automatically.

So these were only examples, my aim is when I write a variable in a function, I want all desired parts to be changed with variable name.

Comment: You should not do this. Learn functional programming and how to use lists. Your approach is bad practice (use of `<<-` is an obvious sign of bad practice) and will lead to pain further down the road.

Comment: @NelsonGon Thank you, I am getting used to it day to day.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for advice, actually I have just started to study R three days ago. I am trying to improve myself everyday. I used 'list' at the beginning, but I could not obtain results' name, so I discovered the using of <<-.

Comment: The proper way is this general approach `yourresult <- yourfunction(yourinput)`. A function can return a list containing a collection of result values. What you should never do (and really don't need to do) is your function creating the symbol `yourresult` to which the return value is bound. That is bad practice (it's called a "side effect").